# IUserIdProvider - ConnectionId is not set

Tags: .net, connection, signalr

**Code**:

```
Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(GetType(IUserIdProvider), Function() New CustomUserIdProvider())
        app.MapSignalR()
    End Sub
    End Class

Public Class CustomUserIdProvider
Implements IUserIdProvider
    Public Function GetUserId(request As IRequest) As String Implements IUserIdProvider.GetUserId
        Return request.Cookies("user_id").Value.ToLower()
    End Function
End Class
```

**Facts**:

- The cookie is set before the GetUserId function is called
- The cookie value is "administrator"

**Problems**:

$.connection.hub.id returns a guid... Is should return "administrator".

```
context.Clients.AllExcept(CurrentUser.ID.ToLower()).broadcastMessage(_inputText.Text)
```

Sends the message to all users, even the one with cookie user_id="administrator".

**Question**:

Why is the returned UserId not used by SignalR ? It's ignored and replaced by a new GUID.

**PS**: I used some breakpoints to be sure that the GetUserId function is called in the CustomUserIdProvider class.

Comment: Context.ConnectionId also returns a Guid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `CurrentUser` comes from in your code, anyway, both `$.connection.hub.id` and `Context.ConnectionId` are managed by SignalR and they do are guids. The value you are emitting from your implementation of `IUserIdProvider` is used to *mark* incoming connections, so that you can retrieve all the connections from a specific user by calling `Context.User()` and passing a key matching the ones you are generating in `IUserIdProvider`. You do not have to expect the connection ids to be changed, that will not happen with your code, you have to use `Context.User` to look for connections belonging to any user id you are specifying in your implementation (for example with a cookie).

Answer (score 0):

```
Clients.User(userId)
```

Not

```
Clients.Client(userId)
```